# How to round UP to the next quarter?

Tags: swift, rounding, ios13

So far I have this code that rounds to the nearest quarter, but I was wondering if there is any way to round it always up to the next quarter.

```
let doubleRounded = round(double * 4) / 4
```

Comment: `let doubleRounded = (double * 4).rounded(.up) / 4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ceil()` instead to force your number to round up.

Round up to the next quarter:

```
let someDouble: Double = 34.26
let doubleCeiledUp = ceil(someDouble * 4) / 4     //prints as 34.5
```

If you wanted to force round down, you can use `floor()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Swift but usually every programming language has some kind of "ceil" function which does exactly what you want. In fact "rounding up" to the next natural number. In your case:

`let doubleRoundedUp = ceil(Double * 4) / 4`